# AWS CDK, how to define ElasticSearch Policies?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I'm trying to create an ElasticSearch instance using the CDK (`CfnDomain`). I just cannot figure out what needs to go into the `AccessPolicies` field. It's marked as "any" in the documentation (`object` in .NET which I am using). I tried putting in a string of Json similar to what is used [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-createupdatedomains.html#es-createdomain-configure-access-policies)

which the CDK fails with:

> Amazon.JSII.Runtime.JsiiException: Resolution error:
>   Amazon.JSII.Runtime.JsiiException: Supplied properties not correct for
>   "CfnDomainProps"

I tried making .NET object that would serialize to the correct JSON for the policy with no luck. I have no clue what goes in this field.

This is the field I'm referring to: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/dotnet/api/Amazon.CDK.AWS.Elasticsearch.CfnDomain.html#Amazon_CDK_AWS_Elasticsearch_CfnDomain_AccessPolicies

Anyone have any advice?

Comment: Care to share if you figured it out? : )

Answer (score 2):

The API Documentation does specify AccessPolicies to be defined as an Object but it's actually going to be a PolicyDocument type.

I have a java example here: https://github.com/cloudshiftstrategies/aws-cdk-examples/tree/master/elastic-search-java-app

It should translate over to C# pretty easily!